# parse a string to look for a phrase in C#

Tags: c#, parsing

I am trying to look for one set of numbers and letters in a string.

Here is the phrase that I'm Looking at:

```
Rx: RX15046522B Brand: LEVOTHYROXINE SODIUM Generic: LEVOTHYROXINE SODIUM  NDC: 00378180001 Barcode: 0378180001 Strength: 25 mcg Form: Tablet Color: orange Marking:  Shape: oblong
```

I want to get this part into another string:

```
NDC: 00378180001
```

How would I do that?

Comment: [`What have you tried?`](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) I really hope you are not expecting us writing the code for you. Because this is unlikely to happen.

Comment: String.IndexOf() and String.Substring() can be your friend or use Regex.

Comment: I am not really looking for code im just really looking for the what direction to head. im not really sure if i should look for the NDC text and then set it to look for the 11 numbers after it. Thats all im really looking for. i would rather code it my self and learn something than have someone do it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's always going to be "NDC: [number]", you can use a fairly simple Regular Expression.

```
var re = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"NDC\:\s(\d{11})");
var phrase = "Rx: RX15046522B Brand: LEVOTHYROXINE SODIUM Generic: LEVOTHYROXINE SODIUM NDC: 00378180001 Barcode: 0378180001 Strength: 25 mcg Form: Tablet Color: orange Marking: Shape: oblong";
if (re.IsMatch(phrase))
{
    var match = re.Match(phrase);
    // entire NDC string
    context.Response.Write(match.Value);
    // just the number
    context.Response.Write(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out these pages -- 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228630%28v=vs.80%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Using string.substring would be your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

So you're looking for a pattern of 3 letters, a colon, a space, and 11 numbers?

RegEx

```
[A-Z]{3}\:\s\d{11}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        String S = "Rx: RX15046522B Brand: LEVOTHYROXINE SODIUM Generic: LEVOTHYROXINE SODIUM NDC: 00378180001 Barcode: 0378180001 Strength: 25 mcg Form: Tablet Color: orange Marking: Shape: oblong";

        Regex myRegex = new Regex(@"[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        foreach (Match iMatch in myRegex.Matches(S))
        {
            if (iMatch.Value.Length==11)
            {
            MessageBox.Show(iMatch.Value);
            }
        }
```